# Excel: parse column into variable length rows

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, transpose

I have a column of data in the format below. The characteristics are that the indicator for anew row is an empty cell in the column, but all the blocks are not the same length. I'm looking for a vba solution and thinking there should be some smart array formula to do this.

Thanks.

```
Section

a

b

c

Section

d

e

f

g

Section

h

i

Section
    
j

k

l


becomes:

a b c

d e f g

h I

j k l
```

Here is my first "failed" attempt. It is capturing four rows at a time, but I want it to find the "Section" markers and copy at that point:

```
Sub Macro_C2R()

Dim row1 As Integer
Dim row2 As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

row1 = 1   ' Counter for copies
row2 = 2   ' Counter for pasting

' Change first worksheet name to "col_input"
Worksheets.Item(1).Name = "col_input"
' Add Data
Set NewSheet = Worksheets.Add
NewSheet.Name = "Data"
Sheets("col_input").Select


'Check there are not two blank rows else end
Do While Not (Range("A" + (CStr(row1))) = "" And Not (Range("A" + (CStr(row1 + 1))) = ""))
' Test if cell is "empty" i.e. one empty row
    Do While Not (Range("A" + (CStr(row1))) = "")
        Range(Cells.Item(row1, 1), Cells.Item(row1 + 4, 1)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Data").Select
        Range(Cells.Item(row2, 1), Cells.Item(row2, 1)).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
            , Transpose:=True
' Increment for next copy
        row1 = row1 + 4
' Increment line counter for next paste
        row2 = row2 + 1
' Back to first page
        Sheets("col_input").Select
     Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

Here is my latest attempt, which "almost" works but it misses the last section:

```
Sub copyandpaste()

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
blck = 1
j = 2

For i = 2 To LastRow + 1
    If Cells(i, 1) = "Section" Then
        Range(Cells(blck, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).Copy
        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        blck = i
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an integer to save the coordinates of the cells you want to write your result in.

```
Dim targetColumn as integer
Dim targetRow as integer
targetRow = 5 'replace this with the line you want your result in
targetColumn = 1
```

I would propose to use two nested loops. The first runs through each line, the seconds through cell of the row.

```
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer

for i = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
   for j = 1 to Cells (i, Columns.Count).End(x1ToLeft).Column
      -> this parses through each cell
   Next 
Next
```

The next thing is to implement that the value of the cell will be written in the new line and the cell will be cleared

```
Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
targetColumn = targetColumn + 1
Cells(i, j).Value = ""
```

Now combine this and it should work.

```
Sub parse()    
Dim targetColumn as integer
Dim targetRow as integer
targetRow = 5 'replace this with the line you want your result in
targetColumn = 1

Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer

for i = 1 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'parses through each row with first cell not empty. 
   for j = 1 to Cells (i, Columns.Count).End(x1ToLeft).Column 'parses through each column in row i
      Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
      targetColumn = targetColumn + 1
      Cells(i, j).Value = ""
   Next 
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONCATENATE function. Examples of its use are available at the link below.

[CONCATENATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)

As the VBS solution in Excel, I get your output when I write your data to cells A1, A3, A5, A7, A9 and combine it with the CONCATENATE function in A11. VBA code is below.

```
Sub Makro1()
Range("A11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(R[-10]C,R[-8]C,R[-6]C,R[-4]C,R[-2]C)"
Range("A12").Select
End Sub
```